# Encrypting secret data in kubernetes etcd store

Tags: security, encryption, kubernetes, etcd, confidentiality

By default all the data stored in etcd is not encrypted, for the production deployments, some of the data stored in etcd need to be encrypted such as secrets, Is there a way to store the secrets, in an encrypted way, in etcd, by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have encryption you need to instruct `apiserver` service with this parameter:

`--experimental-encryption-provider-config=/var/lib/kubernetes/encryption-config.yaml`

where the yaml file contains this:

```
kind: EncryptionConfig
apiVersion: v1
resources:
  - resources:
      - secrets
    providers:
      - aescbc:
          keys:
            - name: key1
              secret: ${ENCRYPTION_KEY}
      - identity: {}
```

here the provider is aescbc (the strongest encryption) and the variable is generated before:

```
ENCRYPTION_KEY=$(head -c 32 /dev/urandom | base64)
```

Take a look to these documents:

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/encrypt-data/
- https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way/blob/master/docs/06-data-encryption-keys.md (and the following md files)

Comment: where is etcd storing the encryption keys? Do I need a separate external etcd cluster ?

Comment: etcd doesn't store the key. The key (only one - symmetric) is in the yaml file, you generated it.

Comment: once you push this yaml file , it will instruct the kubernetes to store secrets encrpted with that key , so where this key reside in kubernetes? how to secure this key

Comment: In the master's memory I suppose, precisely in the apiserver process memory.

Comment: so if the apiserver nodes are restarted, the key will need to be re configured?

Comment: I suggest to you to follow the tutorial at https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way to clear all your doubts.

Comment: the tutorial says nothing about where that key is stored in kubernetes control plane